# How should I display a pdf file in browser using Spring web app?

Tags: java, html, ajax, spring

How should I display this byte code into the WebPage of my app?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getPdf", method=RequestMethod.POST)

public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPDF1() {
String PATH_FILE = "C:\\Users\\rohit\\Downloads\\pdf_view\\sample.pdf";
        
      Path path = Paths.get(PATH_FILE);
        byte[] pdfContents = null;
        try {
            pdfContents =Files.readAllBytes(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
        String filename = "pdf1.pdf";
        headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename);
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(pdfContents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

> I simply want to display my PDF file in my web application.

Answer (score 0):

if you simply want to display your pdf file in your web application you can just drag you pdf into your solution and use href="" to show it I think.
ps: not sure